# Incorrect attribute value type when creating modules

Tags: azure, terraform

My existing code successfully deploys 2 x log analytic workspaces in different regions in azure in their own region based resource groups.

Now I've got one step further and created a law module but I'm receiving the following error:

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on ..\..\..\modules\common\law\main.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces":
│    4:   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_group_name is tuple with 1 element
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "resource_group_name": string required.
╵
╷
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on ..\..\..\modules\common\law\main.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces":
│    4:   resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.resource_group_name is tuple with 1 element
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "resource_group_name": string required.
```

My code below:

**module/rg/main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.location
  tags     = var.tags
}
```

**module/rg/outputs.tf**

```
output "resource_group_name_id" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg[*].id
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg[*].name
  description = "name of resource group"
}

output "location" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg[*].location
  description = "location of resource group"
}

output "tags" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.rg[*].tags
}
```

**module/rg/variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "name of resource group"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
}

variable "tags" {
  type    = map(any)
  default = {}
}
```

**module/law/main.tf**

```
   resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces" {
      name                = var.name
      location            = var.location
      resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
      sku                 = var.sku
      retention_in_days   = var.retention_in_days
    }
```

**module/law/outputs.tf**

```
    output "workspace_id" {
      value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces.id
    }
    
    output "workspace_name" {
      value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces.name
    }
    output "resource_group_name" {
      value = var.resource_group_name

}
```

**module/law/variables.tf**

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "location" {
  description = "The location of the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  description = "The name of the resource group for the Log Analytics workspace."
}

variable "retention_in_days" {
  description = "The retention period in days for Log Analytics data."
}

variable "sku" {
  description = "The sku for the Log Analytics data."
}
```

**main.tf**

```
module "rg"{
  for_each = var.locations
source = "../../../modules/common/rg"

  resource_group_name     = "${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-management-rg"
  location = each.value.region
}


module "law" {
  for_each = var.locations
  source = "../../../modules/common/law"

  name                = "${each.key}-${var.company_prefix}-management-log"
  location            = each.value.region
  resource_group_name = module.rg[each.key].resource_group_name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = var.retention_in_days
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "deployment_environment" {
  description = "Deployment environment"
  type        = string
  default = "p"
}

variable "company_prefix" {
  description = "Company prefix for naming resources"
  type        = string
  default = "lp"
}

variable "retention_in_days" {
  description = "Number of days to retain logs"
  type        = number
  default     = 30
}

variable "locations" {
  description = "Map of location identifiers to Azure region names"
  type = map(object({
    region = string
  }))
  default = {
    ause = {
      region = "australiasoutheast"
    },
    auea = {
      region = "australiaeast"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see, it seems  you have only one `azurerm_resource_group.rg` in your `rg` module. Thus the `resource_group_name` output should be:

```
output "resource_group_name" {
  value       = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  description = "name of resource group"
}
```

You may need to check other outputs for the same issue.

Comment: bingo.  @marcin how did you get so good with TF?  I am going to commence python training soon, hoping it would help me understand things little more

Comment: @Cyborganizer Keep using TF and you will get automatically better with time. TF is largely different than Python.